# $|(A+x) \cap A| \leq 1$, for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, $x \neq 0$.

Tags: additive-combinatorics

Let $n$ be a positive integer.
If $k$ is an integer such that $2^{k+1} \leq n$, then $A=\{1,2,2^2,...,2^{k-1},2^k\}$ is a subset in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $|(A+x) \cap A| \leq 1$, for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, $x \neq 0$.

Indeed, if $y,z \in (A+x)\cap A$, $y=2^a+x=2^b$ and $z=2^c+x=2^d$. So, $x=2^b-2^a=2^d-2^c$ and $2^c+2^b=2^d+2^a$ $\implies$ ($a=b$ and $d=c$) or ($a=c$ and $b=d$) $\implies x=0$ or $y=z$.

$|A|=k+1$.
Is it possible to find a subset $B$ with  $|B|>k+1$ and such that $|(B+x) \cap B| \leq 1$, for all $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$, $x \neq 0$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a restriction on the maximum number in $B$?

Comment: see the following sequence for an example: http://oeis.org/A005282

Comment: Something is a little off here, if our set is $A = \left\{1,2,4,8,16,32\right\}$ and $x=30$ and $n=54$. The assertion that $|(A+x)\cap A|\le 1$ doesn't hold. Even though all the conditions are satisfied.

Comment: I have edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very closely related to [Golomb rulers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler), which are the analogous sets in $\mathbb Z$ rather than $\Bbb Z_n$. Golomb rulers are themselves essentially [Sidon sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence). Fortunately, many good constructions of Sidon sets are actually Sidon sets modulo $n$ for certain types of integers $n$, such as those of the form $p^2-p$ or $p^2-1$ or $p^2+p+1$ for primes $p$. See section 2.2 of [my paper with Kevin O'Bryant](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/index.shtml?abstract=CGSS) for some of these constructions gathered in one place.

The powers of $2$ give a Sidon set in $\Bbb Z_n$ of size about $\log n$. Generally speaking, the largest Sidon sets should be much larger, around $\sqrt n$. Admittedly the above reference doesn't prove this for all $n$ (just those special $n$), but they should get you calibrated at least.